# Create directory recursively if it does not exist?

Tags: javascript, fs

I want to write to a file:

```
fs.writeFile(`${path}/${filename}`, body, err => {
    if (err) throw err
});
```

Before I can write a want to make sure that the directory exists so that `fs.writeFile` does not throw an error

```
fs.mkdir(path, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
});
```

But now `fs.mkdir` will throw an error if the directory does not exists.

Which leads to my question.

How can I asynchronously write to a file and create folders recursively if they do not exist, yet throw no error if they do exits?

Comment: Which version of Node are you using? For Node > 10.12.0, `fs.mkdir`, with the recursive option set, should create the directory for you.

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares: I have node v13.3.0. I get the error message Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir

Comment: Are you sure it's `fs.mkdir` throwing the error and not `fs.writeFile`? Any chance you are calling the latter before the former completes? You might want to use the `Sync` versions of these APIs.

Comment: Oh, I think it might be because I am trying to create a folder, but have already created a file with the same name. Thank you for helping me think.

Comment: Sometimes, all you need is a rubber duck :)